# Help understanding how to prove that $S = \{ \frac{1}{n+1} : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ has $Sup(S) = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

My claim for this problem is that $Sup(S) = \frac{1}{2}$.
To show this we must first show that $\frac{1}{2}$ is an upper bound for S.
Proof: Since $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{2}$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{2}$ is an upper bound for $S$. Do I need to expand this more? Or is this sufficient to show that $\frac{1}{2}$ is an upper bound?
If not, I could rephrase this portion of the proof as Let $x\in S$ be given. Then $x \in \mathbb{N}$, so $x \geq 1$. Therefore, $x+1 \geq 2$ and thus $\frac{1}{x+1} < \frac{1}{2}$.

Furthermore, I would like to show that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if $x$ is an upper bound of $S$, then $\frac{1}{2} \leq x$. 
Using contraposition of this statement: for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if $\frac{1}{2} > x$, then $x$ is not an upper bound of $S$. 
I am struggling to prove this portion of the proof. I have an idea of using the Archimedian Property, in which $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$. But I have not been able to implement this into my proof. Any help and or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: First part: any $x>\frac12$ can be an upper bound too, you need the exact upper bound that can't be lowered more. And prove it) Second part: right, and 'if $\frac{1}{2} > x$, then $x$ is not an upper bound of $S$' -- because $\frac12\in S$

Comment: If $\frac{1}{2}>x$ and $\frac{1}{2}\in S$, then clearly $x$ is not an upper bound of $S$, as this would mean $x\geq\frac{1}{2}$, which is a contradiction

Comment: Why can't you just note that $1/2$ is an element of $S$ implies that $\sup(S) \geq 1/2$ and note that $1/(n + 1) \leq 1/2$ for all natural numbers $n$ implies that $\sup(S) \leq 1/2$? Together the two imply that $\sup(S) = 1/2$.

Comment: We need to use the definition of Least upper bound from my textbook to prove this. I should have noted this in my proof, my apologies.